# prometheus / monitor docker container performance

Tags: prometheus

I have coreos machines which are monitored by prometheus server.

I wish to check the container performance and other parameters. for example, check the container cpu or if container is stopped/restarting/running.

Im trying to find exporter for that, but didn't find anything. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want cAdvisor: https://github.com/google/cadvisor

But if you're running CoreOS, that means Kubernetes, right?  cAdvisor is built into the Kubelet, so you just need to scrape each node on the right port - see https://www.weave.works/blog/aggregating-pod-resource-cpu-memory-usage-arbitrary-labels-prometheus/